# Does Hibernate query caching have any effect if it's used as a JPA provider only?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

Hibernate offers to select different cache providers for query and L2 caching, but there seems to be no clear statement whether this has an effect if Hibernate is used as plain JPA provider only, i.e. by running queries with `EntityManager` instead of `Session`. All introductions simply speak of Hibernate which can mean Hibernate with Hibernate-specific features or Hibernate as JPA provider and then provide code examples involving Hibernate - to advertise the use or because it's a necessity?

In case that matters, I'm referring to a Java EE environment.

Comment: @Eugene I'm willing to improve the clarity of my question, but I don't see the connection between "there are things that Hibernate can do, that JPA can't out of the box" and unclarity. I'm not contradicting this statement and I have to be aware of that difference in order to be able to ask this question.

Comment: @Eugene What case? Please explain what is unclear to you in form of a logical contradiction or an example for irrelevance.

Comment: sorry Ill retract my comments, I might need to read this one tomorrow again, because right now I dont understand your question (but it might be me)

Answer (score 0):

Use of the caching provider is only a matter of configuration of Hibernate. `EntityManager` is only thin wrapper around `Session`. FYI since Hibernate version 5.2 `Session` extends `EntityManager`, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html .

So answer is - Hibernate uses all of their power even when used through JPA.

**EDIT:**

You can ensure that `EntityManager` is wrapper around `Session` by code like this:

```
EntityManager em = ...; // Get EntityManager from somewhere
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
```

If you use Hibernate then you will successefully get `session` wrapped by `EntityManager` and can to use it directly.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. 1. If `EntityManager` is a wrapper around `Session` wouldn't the inheritance be the other way around, i.e. `EntityManager` extending `Session` (which isn't possible) 2. If the "all power" function is in `Session`, how does that show that I get it when retrieving an `EntityManager` from `Persistence`?

Comment: No, `EntityManager` has not extend `Session`. Prior Hibernate 5.2 `Session` had not extended `EntityManager`. `EntityManager` just wrapper around `Session` in Hibernate. Even you retrieve `EntityManager` from `Persistence` you get it from Hibernate and Hibernate creates `EntityManager` as wrapper around `Session`.